# How to position a view to almost bottom of another View in ConstrainLayout

Tags: android, xml

I want to put the TOP red View to the BOTTOM of the gray View like in the image.
-note i dont know the height of the Gray View.

Comment: Hi Saif. Welcome to Stack Overflow. I hope that you are well. Please take a moment to review the guidelines for creating questions [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For your question regarding ConstraintLayout, be sure to add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including your XML code. Providing source code enables members to offer more specific advice. Kind Regards.

Comment: We can't help you unless you... post some example codes or what you have tried so long

Comment: Please ask specific question with code examples that can be run by any person that wants to suggest you something about your code. Specially as others mentioned provide us the details of what you have done so far and at which part you are having issues.